# undefined local variable or method `new_password_reset'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
describe "PasswordResets" do
  before(:each) do 
    visit new_password_reset
  end

  it "should contain the title" do
     page.should have_selector("title", text: "Password reset")
  end

end
```

Failure/Error: `visit new_password_reset`
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `new_password_reset' for #

When i do a rake routes in my terminal, i get the below.

```
new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)      password_resets#new
```

Why i am getting a undefined local variable when i run my tests though the route is present.

Comment: Try to use `new_password_reset_path` instead

Comment: @wildandjam?? could you explain more.

Comment: Its Rspec `it` statement, not `if`

Comment: @NikitaChernov: Its the same, it says new_password_resest_path is undefined.

Comment: Its definitely not the `if` issue, `it` is the correct one.

Comment: Do you have `require'spec_helper'` in the file? How file is named? Where it is located?

Comment: @wildandjam Rspec syntax uses `it`, not `if`. If you don't understand the language, please don't edit the question.

Comment: You need to do `visit new_password_reset_path`. Always append `_path` to any route path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either specify the path directly like

```
visit '/password-reset'
```

or 
specify the path method which is '`new_password_reset_path`' and NOT JUST '`new_password_reset`'

```
visit new_password_reset_path
```